# Video freezes with Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, video, vlc

On a fresh Debian testing installation I am not able to watch a video using standard video player such as: parole, VLC or banshee.

Here are the symptoms:

- The sound is OK, but the image is always freezing.
- If I always drag around the video player the image and the sound are OK.
- If I open the video file with Chromium, the image and the sound are OK. (using the chromium player)

I have installed the Intel graphics driver.

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 6b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem appears to be that the output drivers of the players: (I'e tested vlc, draon player, kmplayer, kplayer, gzine, smplayr and gnome Mplayer, all have the same problem).

The following two players, MVP and Totem with the xine backend work.

They work becaue their output driver is set to using the old x11 driver. The same trick works with smplayer and vlc - set the output driver in the preferences to using x11 - instead of xv or vdpau or whatever output driver they're using.

This won't help for games - x11 is slow, but it works fine for videos.

This is a copy of the solution from here:
http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=116074

Comment: In VLC Tools > Preference > Video : Output

Answer (score 2):

**Solve VLC Media Player Video Decoding Problem**:

- Right click on vlc > Tools > Preferences > Input / Codecs > Hardware-accelerated decoding >> **VA-API video decoder via X11**
- Right click on vlc > Tools > Preferences > Video > Output >> **X11 video output (XCB)**